# Completed class definition put on hold as broken code or code not yet written

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question yesterday [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185087/hide-data-sensitive-fields-or-use-a-new-class-when-returning-to-user). It has been put on hold for the following reason:

> "Questions containing broken code or asking for advice about code not
>   yet written are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review. After
>   the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider
>   reopening it."

I'm at a loss as to what is expected of me here.

The class definition is complete - am I supposed to post my entire application to demonstrate an end-to-end use case?

The question doesn't fit on Stack Overflow because the answer is presumably subjective - which is why I asked here.

Short of posting my entire project, I don't know what else to submit. To somebody who has experience writing similar applications, the answer should be obvious: do I pick option one or two (as illustrated in the code)?

Comment: I only just glanced at your post, but titling your code block "Example:" tends to raise suspicion that the code merely serves illustrative purposes and that the OP is really asking a specific question about a specific issue (i.e. a Stack Overflow question - although this one is too broadly worded to be a good fit there), rather than seeking feedback on any/all aspects of the code. Seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're seeking advice on how to implement something. You're trying to figure out how to "return data sensitive fields like `id`", which implies that it's not already happening in this code.  If you were otherwise asking for a review, then someone could've removed the specific request for unimplemented code, making the question on-topic again (or just no longer fitting this particular off-topic reason, assuming that the small amount of code posted is not enough for a good review thus would probably warrant another close reason).

You've already mentioned that you've left out your entire project. If you were to post that and remove the off-topic request, it would most likely allow the question to be reopened. We like to see more code posted because that's generally easier to review well and looks a lot less like example code.